# Recovering data from a phone stuck in restore mode

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iphone 4 that is stuck in restore mode after trying to update to ios 6 wirelessly.  Unfortunately, I do not have a recent itunes backup of this phone.

Is there any way to recover my photos from this device before I try to restore it?  Will restoring it wipe all the data on the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an iCloud backup? Do you have Photo Stream enabled? These each provide convenient ways of getting your recent photos.

If not [Dr. Fone](http://www.wondershare.net/DrFoneRecovery) is the best option I can think of. It's not cheap ($70) but if the photos are valuable enough it is worth at least downloading the trial to test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up using Dr. Fone (although the website made me suspect I was getting ripped off..), and it worked great.  Unfortunately, I did not have iCloud or photostream on the phone.  Now that I've recovered my photos I'm backup up to my laptop on a regular basis.